# Asp.net change .net framework 4.0 to 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a web application in asp.net 4.0 but i want to change the .net framework to 3.5.

If i change it in the properties and run the web app it gives me an error :

### Can not load file or assembly AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and can not be loaded.

> **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and can not be loaded.
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. On the basis of the following stack trace of the exception, you can obtain more information about the origin and location of the exception.

i really don't now what to do.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the exception message holds the key to the issue.

> This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and can not be loaded.

`AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery` is targeting .NET 4 (or above), and you're targeting .NET 3.5. So you'll need to find a version of `AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery` that targets .NET 3.5, or target your application at .NET 4.

Looking at the Nuget package for `AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery`, it is only available for .NET 4 and above. So if you want to use that package, your application has to target .NET 4 or above.

Comment: @Jojo https://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog or https://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console

Comment: strange... the only package in my project is 'modernizr'. is this the package that i have to remove?

Comment: @Jojo if there's no package, then you'll need to remove the reference. Also, it is possible that some functionality within your project depends on `AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery` and removing it could have drastic side effects.

Comment: @StevenV: I am also facing the same error, even though I am using .NET 4. Please help.

Comment: @NadeemKhan I would encourage you to ask a new question in the event your problem is different than this question.

Comment: @StevenV: Sure, I am trying installing nuget package manager, if this resolves my issue then fine otherwise I will ask a new question. Thanks :)